# Programmatically create JMS objects in Glassfish 3.1.2

Tags: glassfish, jms

I'm using Glassfish 3.1.2.

Is it possible to administer the server via some kind of a Java code? And I don't mean running `asadmin` command via the Process class.

For example, I'd like to create a JMS queue. Usually I'd created it like:

- login into the Admin console
- go to Resources / JMS Resources
- Destination Resources
- press New button

Comment: i wonder if it can be done with JMX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've settled down with calling asadmin from java program.

Answer (score 2):

Well you could create a project that has a glassfish-resources.xml file specifying the Destination Resources like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
    <admin-object-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="jms/NewMessage"  res-type="javax.jms.Queue"  res-adapter="jmsra">
        <property name="Name" value="PhysicalQueue"/>
    </admin-object-resource>
    <connector-connection-pool name="jms/NewMessageFactoryPool"  connection-definition-name="javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory"  resource-adapter-name="jmsra"/>
    <connector-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="jms/NewMessageFactory" pool-name="jms/NewMessageFactoryPool"  />
</resources>
```

And you could write a simple Java program that modifies this file. Each time you deploy this "empty" project, the destination will be created (if it doesn't already exists).

You can see a tutorial of how create an enterprise application using this in the [Netbeans wiki](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/maven-entapp.html).

Comment: Great idea. But I've also found out that Glassfish supports a REST interface to manage the various parts of Glassfish. One article about it can be found at http://kalali.me/how-rest-interface-covers-for-the-absence-of-jmxamx-administration-and-management-interface-in-glassfish-3-1/